# Python: Trying to access different dictionaries in an imported file, based on variable given

Tags: python, dictionary

I have been making a simple turn based 'board game' in python using a separate file to hold all of the data, such as what the attributes of a space is and the attributes of the players. All of this is stored in separate dictionaries. My problem lies in when I need to access or change data for specific players.

So far I have been doing it like this just so I can get it working and just focus on making it work:

```
def function(self): #self is the player number for that turn
    if self == 1:
        database.player1.update(data=0)
    if self == 2:
        database.player2.update(data=0)
...
```

and so on for all four players.

So what I tried to do instead was have something that went like this:

```
def function(self):
    a = 'player' + (self)
    database.a.update(data=a)
```

However unsurprisingly this won't work, but is there a way to get something like this where I am able to determine which dictionary to access based on self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use getattr

```
def function(self):
    a = 'player'+str(self)
    getattr(database,a).update(data=0)
```

`getattr` takes two arguments - the first is the object on which to retrieve the attribute (in your case your `database` module), the second is the name (string) of the attribute to retrieve (in your case `"player1"`, `"player2"`, etc).